# Two-way updatable iCal files in .NET

Tags: .net, icalendar

I've been trying to create an iCal calendar in .NET that can be synced with other devices. I've been using [DDay.iCal](http://www.ddaysoftware.com/Pages/Projects/DDay.iCal/) to generate iCal events from my data objects, and so far everything's working fine. From Outlook, I've subscribed to the calendar (*Add Calendar* » *From Internet*) by pointing to a URL that generates an ics file:

```
Response.Clear();
Response.ContentType = "text/calendar";
Response.AddHeader("Content-Disposition", "inline; filename=\"Calendar.ics\"");
Response.Write( GenerateCalendar() );
Response.End();
```

The events are properly imported into the calendar; however, in any Calendar software I've tried, I have been unable to update or delete events. It's not that there is an error in receiving the delete notification; it's simply that all clients recognize the calendar as read-only.

My idea is that by supplying URLs, I would be able to have Outlook or Google calendar contact my server in order to delete an event. Is my entire idea of how this is supposed to work wrong, or am I just missing out on the proper properties? (Or, perhaps, am I importing the calendar incorrectly, or distributing it incorrectly, as per the code above?)

A calendar generated by `GenerateCalendar` above, may look something like this:

```
BEGIN:VCALENDAR
VERSION:2.0
METHOD:PUBLISH
PRODID:-//My Company//My App//EN
URL:http://localhost/test/
X-WR-CALNAME:Test
BEGIN:VEVENT
DTEND:20110831T100100
DTSTAMP:20111028T091109
DTSTART:20110831T090100
SEQUENCE:0
SUMMARY:Test
UID:1
URL:http://localhost/test/?id=1
END:VEVENT
END:VCALENDAR
```

Comment: Hi David. I need to create a CalDAV-Server for my .NET Application which contains a Calendar to Sync it with iPhone and other mobile devices. I would ask you if you can point me in a direction? Or perhaps we can do something together?

Comment: @t.kehl: I never started building an entire CalDAV implementation. I think the best option would be to install Exchange server-side and have the mobile devices sync with that, and use your application to push things to Exchange. (I have not embarked on that myself either, though, so I don't really have any pointers)

Answer (score 1):

My understanding is that you need to host your calendar on a CalDAV server (https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc4791). Simply publishing a file (.ics) is different from hosting a calendar on a calendar engine.

Comment: Thanks. I've been looking in that direction as well. Do you know of any .NET CalDAV server? I've mostly found mac-stuff and some php and python setups so far. Otherwise, I'll probably drop iCal and look to use Exchange as a messaging layer...

Comment: I'm not aware of any .NET CalDAV server. I'm sure you've seen [this](http://caldav.calconnect.org/implementations/servers.html) already. Can you turn the problem on its head: assume a hosted server (say Google) and populate a hosted calendar through CalDAV client API calls?

Comment: my bounty was about to expire; you may have it. I don't think I'll assume a hosted server, but I may look into writing a port of one of the open source java ones from your list. Either that or just using Exchange as a messaging layer... I'd rather host my own stuff, anyhow...

Comment: I wasn't really after the bounty - thanks though. I have had the same problem myself and eventually gave up due to not wanting to get into understanding the complexities of running a CalDAV server, notably how to merge the notion of accounts of that server with my own. At the time, my conclusion was that the best option is to use the Python-based [Apple version](http://calendarserver.org) because it appears to be actively maintained, and also I run my servers on Linux w/ the Mono stack for .NET apps.

Comment: Here is the CalDAV server example and library in .Net: http://www.webdavsystem.com/server/server_examples/caldav_carddav_csharp

Answer (score 1):

Had the exact same problem and I solved it by installing davmail server and posted calendar events thru it with php. It can be configured with http basic authentication which is relative easy to use with things like CURL. Davmail has nice documentation and setup guides for various devices

To make it really 2-way you can just store credential info of users and make request with crontab or something similar.

Answer (score 0):

I think that you should be able to get it to work by changing the METHOD from PUBLISH to REQUEST and adding an ORGANIZER entry to the VEVENT block, even if it is a dummy email address.

For more details see [RFC 2446](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc2446#page-19)

Comment: Thanks, but I'm still having issue. And even if I did get the calendar client to recognize that I want changes to be allowed, how do I get notified when changes are made. Is the client supposed to send a request to the `URL` property?

Comment: I don't think that you are going to get an interactive response directly back to your application. I suspect that could be seen as a fairly significant security hole. However, if you setup a well-known email address as the organizer and then create an application that monitors this email address, you should be able to receive the responses that are generated by users accepting or cancelling the invite request and update your internal calendar from those responses.

Comment: Well that's part of my problem: Even when specifying an organizer, that properly shows up in Outlook as the organizer, I'm still not receiving any responses on that address when the user clicks "Accept". But I think that's actually a bit off course from what I want: There are several multi-client solutions where calendars are synced two-way. I can't see why I shouldn't be able to; the security is something I'll have to worry about, obviously. Is it just that it's not possible *within the scope of the iCal format*? In that case I guess my question is: what format *can* I use, to provide a

Comment: calendar that I can sync with a calendar client of my choice, and update from either my software, or the 3rd party calendar software, such as Outlook or Google Calendar?

Answer (score 0):

I know the ["IP*Works! Internet Toolkit"](http://www.nsoftware.com/ipworks/technologies.aspx?sku=IPN8-A) has support for [WebDav](http://www.nsoftware.com/products/component/caldav.aspx).